# Can I call location.reload() from HttpResponseRedirect?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call `location.reload()` when using `HttpResponseRedirect` using Django? I have a function that changes the state of an item when a button is clicked. Often the user scrolls down to click this button. The button is hooked up to the view `change_state`:

```
def change_state(request, item_title, new_state):
    modify_state(item_title, new_state)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('slug-of-prev-page'))
```

When I redirect to `slug-of-prev-page` the entire page will reload, snapping the page to the top. I know using something that manipulates the DOM, like React.js, would be better for this type of thing. But I'm looking for a quick solution. Or is my best bet to hook up a call to `change_state`, `POST` the data, and then call `location.reload()`?

Comment: How is this a django question actually ? Your issue would be __exactly__ the same whatever techno is used on the backend side...

Comment: If I want to redirect in Django using syntax in Django or an extension, is that a philosophical programming question? Or am I asking a programming implementation question? Or is it only possible using JavaScript?

Comment: The fact you're using django's `HTTPResponseRedirect` is totally irrelevant - what the HTTP client sees is the exact same HTTP response a couple of PHP `header()` calls with the same HTTP response code and redirect url would generate. IOW, it's only an HTTP / javascript question and has nothing to do with the backend.

Comment: So mimicking 'location.reload()' is not possible using Django? I must rewrite everything to get handled in JS?

Comment: Oh, and this still has nothing to do with Django BTW - you'd have the very same situation with PHP, ASP, Springs, Tomcat, Ruby on Rails, or just whatever backend techno...

Comment: I see my last comment was somehow deleted, so I wanted to point out again how unhelpful you've been, and that you ignored my last two questions. I think you could have answered this in a much friendlier manner.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't get the point - your question(s), as formulated, don't really make sense. `window.location.reload()` is a client-side operation (which, mostly, asks the client to send a new request to the current url and re-render the response), and you cannot "mimick" this server-side.